# 18.04 Screen Resolution Problem NVIDIA GT 710

Tags: nvidia, display-resolution

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 on a PC with an NVIDIA GeForce GT 710 graphics card then applied update through 'additional driver' set up.

I want 1360x768 (16:9) screen resolution to match the monitor, but Ubuntu reverts to 1024x768 (4:3).

I tried both nouveau and the NVIDIA  proprietary driver with the same result.

How do I get Ubuntu to show 1360 x 768?

Comment: Faced the same issue in Kubuntu 18.04. Everything's fine with nouveau driver, resolution is 1920x1080, but doesn't work with recent NVidia drivers (tried 435 from Ubuntu repos and 440 from NVidia ppa).

Comment: Do you have Secure Boot enabled? I fixed the issue when installing NVIDIA driver. If Secure Boot is enabled then you will be asked for MOK password during driver installation. You have to set it and enter it after reboot to make the driver to work.